# Призыв голосовать "за"

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, вопросы, репутация

Можно ли на ресурсах *Stack Overflow* задавать вопросы и специально просить людей чтобы они голосовали "ЗА", чтобы повысить репутацию и получать достижения? Чем карается такое поведение?

Comment: карается знаками [Диктор](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer), [Усилитель](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/60/booster), [Публицист](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/61/publicist)

Comment: Заголовок не соответствует вопросу. А ещё у вопросов нет репутации — это атрибут участника (учётной записи). Число рядом с вопросом — это рейтинг.

Comment: @NickVolynkin заголовок поправлен. Голосование за вопрос повышает репутацию ТС, всё логично вроде.

Comment: @Denis  А кто вам может запретить просить своих знакомых голосовать за ваш вопрос? Главное - это собрать как можно более многочисленную группу поддержки!

Comment: @Denis `просить людей чтобы они голосовали "ЗА"` - за свои вопросы/ответы или за чужие?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

По моим субъективным ощущениям, в сообществе ruSO не принято просить проголосовать «за».

Если вы специально попросите людей проголосовать, а вопрос им не понравится, то они проголосуют против. Получится обратный желаему результат. Поэтому главное, чтобы вопросы были качественными: интересными, грамотно написанными и хорошо оформленными. Тогда и без привлечения внимания будет приток репутации.

Есть «легальная» форма привлечения внимания — открыть конкурс, стоит минимум 50 репутации. «Окупится» плюсами, только если вопрос действительно хорош и интересен многим. Просто сложный и хорошо оформленный вопрос по непопулярной теме скорее не окупится — да и не для этого конкурсы придуманы.

Если вам хочется поскорее набрать сколько-то репутации, лучше попробуйте отвечать на вопросы. За *хорошие* ответы дается больше репутации.

И на всякий случай: если кто-то будет голосовать «за» ваши вопросы и ответы специально, просто потому что они ваши — вот это обнаруживается и карается.

Comment: Печально другое (правда не не в русском SO), создает товарищ вопрос, потому что влом 20 минут загуглить, ему пишут 3 ответа, у ничего не выходит, потому что он банально не знает основ и он лепит всем ответившим минусы. Вот примерчик http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337865/insert-query-not-being-fired/42337945#42337945

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov На русском (да и на английском тоже) SO нужно набрать 125 репутации, чтобы иметь возможность проголосовать против, так-что там проголосовал не автор вопроса

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov подозреваю, минусы расставил кто-то, осуждающий предложенные пути решения. Возможно, вот это решение он посчитал бы более правильным. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324591/how-to-avoid-a-syntax-error-when-adding-a-variable-into-sql-query-in-php

Comment: А автор вопроса может минусы ставить?

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov если имеет 125 репутации.

Comment: Кстати я хочу отметить, что в RU SO, народ более терпимый (ну по крайней мере мне встречались) - если ошибка, то об этом пишут, а не лепят сразу минусы.